# Discord.py Reaction Roles with custom emojis

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have been working on a discord bot for reaction roles. The idea is it registers the message, the role, and the emoji to a .JSON file and executes the role update on `on_raw_reaction_remove` or `on_raw_reaction_add`

Now, the problem is it DOES ADD the custom reactions to the specified message. However, it doesn't give the respected role on reaction_add. I couldn't find a way to fix this problem. My opinion is that the problem could be the way the bot registers custom emojis. Here is an example:

```
[
    {
        "role_id": 897227510574616656,
        "emoji": "\ud83d\ude04",
        "message_id": "898215881136570418"
    },
    {
        "role_id": 897227510574616656,
        "emoji": "<:custom:898198216611344424>",
        "message_id": "898215881136570418"
    }
]
```

````py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.member.bot:
        pass
    else:
        with open('data.json') as react_file:
            data = json.load(react_file)
            for x in data:
                if x['emoji'] == payload.emoji.name:
                    role = discord.utils.get(client.get_guild(
                        payload.guild_id).roles, id=x['role_id'])

                    await payload.member.add_roles(role)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True, manage_roles=True)
async def add(ctx, msg_id, emoji, role: discord.Role):
    msg= await ctx.fetch_message(msg_id)
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)

    with open('data.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

        new_react_role = {'role_id': role.id,
        'emoji': emoji,
        'message_id': msg_id}

        data.append(new_react_role)

    with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not save the `emoji.name` in the json file, so in your check you would need to do something more like `if x['emoji'] == str(payload.emoji):` for it to work.

```py
else:
    with open('data.json') as react_file:
        data = json.load(react_file)
        for x in data:
            if x['emoji'] == str(payload.emoji):
                role = discord.utils.get(client.get_guild(
                    payload.guild_id).roles, id=x['role_id'])
```

The `emoji.name` would only print out something like `custom` instead of the `<:custom:898198216611344424>` that is saved in your json file. `str(emoji)` prints out the whole thing, like in your file.

Comment: Woot! It worked! But what I don't understand is, with your code it does not change the way it stores data in the JSON file.

To make this clear for me, did ```payload.emoji.name``` stored a spesific part of "emoj" in data.json file?

Comment: No, with your code you have written above you are storing the "whole emoji" with ID and everything in your json file. So in your check you have to compare the whole emoji string with the whole emoji string. And in your code above you have basically compared the whole emoji string with only the emoji name. 

Example on what your code did: `if "<:custom:898198216611344424>" == "custom"`. So your if statement would never trigger. The snippet of mine would do: `if "<:custom:898198216611344424>" == "<:custom:898198216611344424>"`.

Hope that kind of makes sense